# Check box always returning true

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble getting this to work properly I only have one check box if its check I want it to return `Yes` if its not checked I would like it to return 0 or whatever it does when its not checked. For some reason it is always getting passed as "Yes" can someone spot the error in my code I have been looking at other posts and it seems like I have it setup right.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="lunchCheck" value="Yes" name="lunch" checked />
```

Here is my javascript where I get the value

```
window.lunch = document.getElementById("lunchCheck").value;
```

Comment: It's **always** being passed "Yes" because you're **always** retrieving its `value`. `value` is different from `checked` and are unrelated (in your context at least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the "checked" property.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('lunchCheck');
window.lunch = elem.checked ? elem.value : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to check if its checked first, then get the value

```
window.lunch = document.getElementById("lunchCheck").checked ? document.getElementById("lunchCheck").value : "";
```